# EditText selection anchor

Tags: android

I have a listview, where each row is an EditText, with some text. When I tap on a row, EditText gets the focus, displays the blinking cursor and the selection anchor (you know the blue/gray looking handles that you drag around to select a range of text).

The **problem** is that when I move from one row to another (edittext to another), without enterting new text, the selection anchor in the previous edittext remains visible for a while. I would like to hide this anchor immediately if the edittext doesn't have focus.

Any ideas?

**ClearFocus Doesn't work**

```
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {             
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {

                } else {
                    editText.clearFocus();
                    //editText.clearComposingText();                        
                }
            }
        });
```

**Screenshot**

[image: The Problem]

Comment: It is weird, have you tested it on other devices ??

Comment: well the only 'solution' is trying to call clearFocus() on all of the other cells when one of your edittexts gains focus, or maybe your adapter is not written the right way.

Try this adapter instead:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Comment: Yeah, I tried clearFocus(), but no luck. I will look at the link, but I don't think it is much different than what I have now. :O

Comment: well then try adding setFocusable(false), and why are you using a list view instead of many edit texts? is it supposed to change dynamically ??

Comment: So I can take advantage of the list view recycling views, as data is being loaded from the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18826/discussion-between-states-and-user1597833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it! First of all, I removed focusability from the `ListView`. Then I wrote a custom `OnFocusChangeListener` that removes the selection from the view that looses the focus. This listener is applied to the views by a custom adapter (I wrapped `ArrayAdapter`, but you can as well wrap a `SimpleCursorAdapter`).

Attached is a demo (tested on an emulator with Eclair):

```
public class ListOfEditViews extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list.setAdapter(getAdapter());
        list.setFocusable(false);
        list.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        setContentView(list);
    }

    private ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.edit_text, R.id.text) {

            @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setFocusable(true);
                view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                view.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
                return view;
            }
        };

        String words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen";

        for (String word: words.split(" "))
            adapter.add(word);

        return adapter;
    }

    private OnFocusChangeListener listener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            view.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Trying it out now. The view returned by getView(..) is that a EditText type?

Comment: hmm, doesn't work :( Now the anchor gets set to the beginning of the edittext, rather than the end. I have a feeling it is a version specific issue.

Comment: @States See the update: I used `view.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)` in the listener... This seems really a hack to me, but works in my tests